# Property 'last' does not exist on type 'NavController'

Tags: angular, ionic7

`if (this.nav.last().instance instanceof SupplierSelectPage) { this.form.controls['SupplierName'].markAsTouched(); }`

I have updated the Ionic version to 7, after that, I am facing issues on the property `last()`.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`ion-nav`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav), you need to try the following methods to access the latest view or by index:

- [`getActive`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav#getactive%7C)
- [`getByIndex`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav#getbyindex)

In your case you can check `.last` to `.getActive`

Comment: I am using NavController